# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window while showing a AlertDialog from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have set Alarm manager I want to show a dialogue box in onReceive method in BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Utils.getINSTANCE().statusCheck(context);
    }
}
```

here is statuscheck method

```
    public void statusCheck(Context context) {
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps(context);

    }
}
private void buildAlertMessageNoGps(final Context context) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    context. startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

I am facing issue token null on alert.show()

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.coin.etheriumclassic.AlarmReceiver: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

How can we do that? If we have to show simple dialogue box in Broadcastreceiver(I do that in broadcastreceiver because I have to show dialogue when device turn on )

Comment: use system alert dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only display an `AlertDialog` from an `Activity`, not a `BroadcastReceiver`.

You *can* start an activity from a `BroadcastReceiver`, and so you can create an activity with a dialog theme (e.g., [`Theme.Material.Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Material_Dialog)), so it is styled like a dialog.

Note, though, that showing a dialog when the device starts up is rather user-hostile, not to mention impractical (e.g., the device has a lockscreen). Consider showing a `Notification` instead.

Comment: thank you so much got the idea of the relationship between Activity and AlertDialog. Thank you so much.